# Get this "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding" combination for ruby

Tags: java, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I have this java code for encryption and decryption, which I want to change/convert to Ruby code. I looked up in OpenSSL gem but dint find the "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding" combination available for ruby. How do I implement it?

```
public class EncryptDecryptService {
    
    public String encryptRequestObject(RequestObject requestObject) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, CertificateException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKey(requestObject.getKeyFilename());
        byte[] message = requestObject.getString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] secret = encrypt(publicKey, message);
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(secret);
    }
    
    public String decryptRequestObject(RequestObject requestObject) throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(requestObject.getKeyFilename(), requestObject.getKeyPassword());
        byte[] cipherText = Base64.decodeBase64(requestObject.getString());
        byte[] decrypted = decrypt(privateKey, cipherText);
        return new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
    }
    
    private PublicKey getPublicKey(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, CertificateException {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filename);
        CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(fin);
        PublicKey publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();
        return publicKey;
    }
    
    private PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String filename, String password) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filename);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        ks.load(fin, password.toCharArray());
        String str = ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(str, password.toCharArray());
        return privateKey;
    }
    
    private byte[] encrypt(PublicKey key, byte[] plainText) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(plainText);
    }
    
    private byte[] decrypt(PrivateKey key, byte[] cipherText) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OAEP uses several parameters, including two digests, one for OAEP (i.e. for hashing the OAEP label) and one for the mask generation function (MGF1), see [RFC8017, sec. 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.1).

The identifier `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding` is ambiguous and depends on the provider. For example the SunJCE provider uses SHA-256 as OAEP digest and SHA-1 as MGF1 digest, the BouncyCastle provider uses SHA-256 for both digests.

The following is an example of the encryption with the Java code and the decryption with the Ruby code (the opposite direction is analog).

---

On the Java side the SunJCE provider is used WLOG and the digests involved are determined:

```
String pubKey = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDNvs/qUMjkfq2E9o0qn03+KJE7" + 
                "ASczEbn6q+kkthNBdmTsskikWsykpDPnLWhAVkmjz4alQyqw+mHYP9xhx8qUC4A3" + 
                "tXY0ObxANUUKhUvR7zNj4vk4t8F2nP3erWvaG8J+sN3Ubr40ZYIYLS6UHYRFrqRD" + 
                "CDhUtyjwERlz8KhLyQIDAQAB";

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(pubKey));
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);

byte[] plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[] ciphertext = encrypt(publicKey, plaintext);

System.out.println("Ciphertext: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ciphertext));
```

with

```
private static byte[] encrypt(PublicKey key, byte[] plainText) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding"); 
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpec = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(OAEPParameterSpec.class);
    MGF1ParameterSpec mgf1ParameterSpec = (MGF1ParameterSpec)oaepParameterSpec.getMGFParameters();
    System.out.println("Provider  : " + cipher.getProvider().getName());
    System.out.println("OAEP-Hash : " + oaepParameterSpec.getDigestAlgorithm());
    System.out.println("MGF1-Hash : " + mgf1ParameterSpec.getDigestAlgorithm());
    return cipher.doFinal(plainText);
}
```

which corresponds to the posted `encrypt()` method (except for the additional output). The code produces (e.g.) the following output:

```
Provider  : SunJCE
OAEP-Hash : SHA-256
MGF1-Hash : SHA-1
Ciphertext: WlozD9ojNRQafip41dpuuhBMe7ruH2FBWnMhbAaSuAtPDpHOUyKaAm6mO15BbvL3eTXyqfEQx29dYPJEbUr5T/WXs846PQN6g7Yv25EXGVbPCzc4aIbms76C1jP92wXNEGWMnu624Fq5W9MVXX75mfaY0Fjvrh5k/TFuO4AIxMk=
```

For completeness it should be mentioned that an explicit specification of the parameters is also possible with:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding"); 
OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"), PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, oaepParameterSpec);
```

whereby this explicit specification is the more robust alternative because of the ambivalence described above.

---

After the digests have been determined (either because the provider is known or explicitly with the above output) a Ruby implementation can be made.

A possible OAEP implementation for Ruby is [openssl-oaep](https://github.com/terashi58/openssl-oaep).

With this, the Ruby code for decryption can be implemented as follows:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'openssl/oaep'
require 'base64'

private_key = 
'-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'

key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(private_key) 
label = ''
md_oaep = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256
md_mgf1 = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1
cipher_text_B64 = 'WlozD9ojNRQafip41dpuuhBMe7ruH2FBWnMhbAaSuAtPDpHOUyKaAm6mO15BbvL3eTXyqfEQx29dYPJEbUr5T/WXs846PQN6g7Yv25EXGVbPCzc4aIbms76C1jP92wXNEGWMnu624Fq5W9MVXX75mfaY0Fjvrh5k/TFuO4AIxMk='
cipher_text = Base64.decode64(cipher_text_B64)
plain_text = key.private_decrypt_oaep(cipher_text, label, md_oaep, md_mgf1)
print(plain_text) # The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

with the original plaintext as output.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco , the decryption is perfect, I have to dig for encryption and I will be good to go.